# Transfer files from UNIX-Cluster to local desktop

Tags: windows, unix, cluster-computing, file-transfer

I'm trying to move a file I have on the Cluster (UNIX) to my local computer (Windows 11) and have tried different solutions for the past 1 hour without any success.

This is the code I'm using:

`scp roger89@rackham3:/home/roger89/cat1.txt C:/Users/Roger/Desktop`

And the error message I keep getting is:

> *ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known lost connection Connection to rackham3 closed.*

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What about credentials for your Windows machine? Are they needed?

Comment: The `scp` program seems to have difficulties with Windows drive letters because `scp`'s command syntax uses `:` to separate the host from the file name. Are you running the `scp` command in a CMD window or maybe in a shell? What version of `scp` did you install? MSys? Cygwin? As a workaround, `cd` to the destination directory and then use the `scp` command with `.` as destination directory.

Comment: This Q seems to be about *using* programs, and  is not about `if-then-else` programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on https://superuser.com OR https://unix.stackexchange.com .  Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good Luck

Comment: I'm running the scp command in a shell (on the cluster). Not sure which version of scp I'm using, as it was pre-installed. The problem with using "." as a destination directory, is that I don't know where my destination directory is. I've tried google "current working directory" of my local windows machine, but getting nowhere. However, when I use . as a destination directory, I don't get any errors. At the same time, I don't know where the files are located.

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  On your Windows desktop, run your scp.  It will copy from the cluster to your desktop.  You pull files from the cluster.  For the `.`, it means the file will be copied in the current directory you are in when you call the scp.  So start a shell window on your desktop, run the scp, run `dir` in the same window, you file will be there.